# Android actionbar tabs multiple fragments in one tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am creating a tabbed application and the main activity for one of the tabs is a listing of departments. When you click on a department it starts a new activity that lists the documents in the department.

My issue is when it shows the document listing, the tabbed view goes away. And I would like to keep the tabs on the top constantly. I have attempted to extend the TabActivity to each of the activities that are started under the tab, but then the listviews create over eachother.

I have also attempted to create the tabs without a tablistener starting an activity, so I can only create the listener if it is the first time the tab is called, but that is not allowed.

Any help would be appreciated, maybe there is some method I am completely missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I would like to keep the tabs on the top constantly.

Then you should not be starting an activity when the user taps on tab. Your tab contents should either be fragments or something else manipulated by your `TabListener`. The concept of activities being the contents of tabs is now deprecated (and, IMHO, was a bad idea to begin with).

> I have attempted to extend the TabActivity to each of the activities that are started under the tab, but then the listviews create over eachother.

You will notice that `TabActivity` is deprecated, specifically for the activities-as-the-contents-of-tabs concept.

Comment: Okay I understand that fragments should be started by clicking a tab, but how do I start another fragment after clicking on the tab and then selecting a department from the listview? Wouldn't I need to start an activity to include the fragment in it's xml layout? And also by TabActivity I meant the activity I use to instantiate my tabs not the deprecated one. Sorry about the confusing question.

Comment: @AaronSmentkowski: You would put the list of departments and the details of the selected department side-by-side in a single tab. Or, you would run another `FragmentTransaction` to replace the list fragment with a details fragment.

Comment: It is another listview of documents that is being created, rather than the details of the department. So it would need to recreate the list with the documents in the selected department.

Comment: @AaronSmentkowski: You would put the list of departments and the list of documents side-by-side in a single tab. Or, you would run another `FragmentTransaction` to replace the list-of-departments fragment with the list-of-documents fragment. Or, you would give the `ListView`, that originally held some sort of `DepartmentAdapter`, a `DocumentsForSomeDepartmentAdapter`. Or whatever floats your proverbial boat.

Comment: FragmentTransaction. Seems like the exact tool I need. Thank you.